# Why are some hashes initialized using curly braces, and some with parentheses?

Tags: perl, hash

I'm looking at the following code demonstrating nested hashes:

```
my %HoH = (
    flintstones => {
        husband   => "fred",
        pal       => "barney",
    },
    jetsons => {
        husband   => "george",
        wife      => "jane",
        "his boy" => "elroy",  # Key quotes needed.
    },
    simpsons => {
        husband   => "homer",
        wife      => "marge",
        kid       => "bart",
    },
);
```

Why is it that the upper-most hash (starting line 1) is initialized using parentheses, whereas the sub-hashes are initialized using curly braces?

Coming from a python background I must say Perl is quite odd :).

Answer (score 30):

Coming from a Perl background I find Perl quite odd, too.

Use parentheses to initialize a hash (or an array). A hash is a map between a set of strings and a set of scalar values.

```
%foo = ( "key1", "value1",  "key2", "value2", ... );   #  % means hash
%foo = ( key1 => "value1",  key2 => "value2", ... );   # same thing
```

Braces are used to define a hash *reference*. All references are scalar values.

```
$foo = { key1 => "value1", key2 => "value2", ... };    #  $ means scalar
```

Hashes are *not* scalar values. Since the values in a hash *must* be scalars, it is therefore not possible to use a hash as a value of another hash.

```
%bar = ( key3 => %foo );     # doesn't mean what you think it means
```

But we can use hash references as values of another hash, because hash references are scalars.

```
$foo = { key1 => "value1", key2 => "value2" };
%bar = ( key3 => $foo );
%baz = ( key4 => { key5 => "value5", key6 => "value6" } );
```

And that is why you see parentheses surrounding a list of lists with braces.

Comment: Just for completeness...while it's true that `key3 => %foo` doesn't do what it seems, `key3 => \%foo` adds a reference and is a very simple way to make it do what one would intend in that situation.

Answer (score 10):

The essential difference  (....) is used to create a hash.  {....} is used to create a hash **reference**

```
my %hash  = ( a => 1 , b => 2 ) ;
my $hash_ref  = { a => 1 , b => 2 } ;
```

In a bit more detail -  {....} makes an **anonymous hash** and returns a reference to it wich is asigned to the scalar `$hash_ref`

*edited to give a bit more detail*

Answer (score 6):

First, the parens do nothing but change precedence here. They never have nothing to do with list creation, hash creation or hash initialisation.

For example, the following two lines are 100% equivalent:

```
{   a => 1, b => 2   }
{ ( a => 1, b => 2 ) }
```

For example, the following two lines are 100% equivalent:

```
sub f { return ( a => 1, b => 2 ) }    my %hash = f(); 
sub f { return   a => 1, b => 2   }    my %hash = f();
```

---

Second, one doesn't initialise a hash using `{ }`; one creates a hash using it. `{ }` is equivalent to `my %hash;`, except that the hash is anonymous. In other words,

```
{ LIST }
```

is basically the same as

```
do { my %anon = LIST; \%anon }
```

(but doesn't create a lexical scope).

Anonymous hashes allows one to write

```
my %HoH = (
    flintstones => {
        husband   => "fred",
        pal       => "barney",
    },
    jetsons => {
        husband   => "george",
        wife      => "jane",
        "his boy" => "elroy",
    },
    simpsons => {
        husband   => "homer",
        wife      => "marge",
        kid       => "bart",
    },
);
```

instead of

```
my %flintstones = (
    husband   => "fred",
    pal       => "barney",
);
my %jetsons = (
    husband   => "george",
    wife      => "jane",
    "his boy" => "elroy", 
);
my %simpsons = (
    husband   => "homer",
    wife      => "marge",
    kid       => "bart",
);
my %HoH = (
    flintstones => \%flinstones,
    jetsons     => \%jetsons,
    simpsons    => \%simpsons,
);
```

Comment: "First, the parens do nothing but change precedence here. They have nothing to do with list creation, hash creation or hash initialisation" This is what I was looking for. Thank you sir. +1