# Printing Hash Pairs in Perl

Tags: perl, hashtable

Please what is the difference between these two hash initialization methods?

**The First Method:**

```
$items{"food"} = "4.4";
$items{"water"} = "5.0";
$items{"shelter"} = "1.1";

foreach $item (keys $items) {
    print "$item\n";
}
```

**The output is:**

```
food
water
shelter
```

**The Second Method:**

```
%items = { 
    'food' => '4.4', 
    'water' => '5.0', 
    'shelter' => '1.1' 
};

foreach $item (keys %items) {
    print "$item\n";
}
```

**The output is a hash reference:**

```
HASH(0x8cc41bc)
```

Why does the second method return a reference instead of the actual values?

Comment: In the second case, you assigned a single reference to an anonymous hash to `%hash`. So, there is only one key: The stringification of the hash reference, and the corresponding `undef` value. Voting to close.

Comment: Thanks Sinan, what modifications would rectify the 2nd instance?

Comment: Either you need to assign a list of key value pairs, as in `my %h = ( ... )`, or assign to a scalar, i.e. `my $h = { ... }`. If you do the latter, use `keys %$h`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Well, it's not just a typo but merely a wrong sigil, which is a different class of error.

Comment: @SinanÜnür `%hash = { }` is not a typo, it's a very common misunderstanding. (I pointed out this same issue to someone [just yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878021/why-does-tr-always-return-zero-when-i-pass-it-a-variable#comment65120038_38878021).) Even though it's not quite a duplicate, it would be better to point the OP to [Why are some hashes initialized using curly braces, and some with parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11839586/176646) than to close as a typo.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot OK, I retracted my close vote (can't vote again), so there is still a chance to close this as a duplicate of the question you recommend. There are currently 2 votes to close as a typo. If everyone else votes to close it as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11839586/), this should work out.

Comment: @zdim It's not so easy to search for special characters like curlies or parens, and Perl is full of them. Google (afaik) filters them out. I sometimes use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=perl+%24%3F).

Comment: @PerlDog Agreed, but the OP itself uses "_hash initialization methods_" and "_hash reference_", for example.  Searching for such things does yield, immediately.

Comment: @PerlDog  Thanks for that SymbolHound reference, it seems interesting! Most of the time I can work my way around special symbols by formulating the query carefully, but it'd be very nice to be able to just type in some of the line noise sometimes :)  Will try it out.

Answer (score 8):

Because you have misunderstood what `{}` does.

It creates an anonymous hash, returning a reference.

What you've just done is functionally similar to:

```
my %stuff = (
   'food' => '4.4', 
    'water' => '5.0', 
    'shelter' => '1.1' 
);


my %items = \%stuff;
```

Which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Use `()` to init the hash, and it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example of why you should **always** turn on warnings in your Perl code.

```
$ perl -Mwarnings -E'%h = {}; say keys %h'
Reference found where even-sized list expected at -e line 1.
HASH(0xbb6d48)
```

For more detailed explanation, use "diagnostics" too.

```
$ perl -Mwarnings -Mdiagnostics -E'%h = {}; say keys %h'
Reference found where even-sized list expected at -e line 1 (#1)
    (W misc) You gave a single reference where Perl was expecting a list
    with an even number of elements (for assignment to a hash). This usually
    means that you used the anon hash constructor when you meant to use
    parens. In any case, a hash requires key/value pairs.

        %hash = { one => 1, two => 2, };        # WRONG
        %hash = [ qw/ an anon array / ];        # WRONG
        %hash = ( one => 1, two => 2, );        # right
        %hash = qw( one 1 two 2 );              # also fine

HASH(0x253ad48)
```